# iOS Alpha StackExchange scroll to top missing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

So having signed up and downloaded the new alpha for iOS I found a small "bug" (*just a small thing I've noticed, I wouldn't describe it as a bug necessarily hence the quotes around bug*).

When looking at my answers and clicking on one, it takes me to my answer within the answers of all users. That is fine.

But when trying to go to top (on the iPhone, tapping on the top part of the screen) it won't do anything and you have to manually scroll up.

I should also add that I didn't expect this version to be that impressive!

Comment: Reproduced on v0.1.54. Same problem when I do a search and tap on an answer. No problem when I tap on a question.

Comment: I was able to reproduce on v0.1.56. I'm seeing the same as above. No problem on the question, just the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for finding this tiny, yet annoying, edge case.

This will be fixed in **version 0.1.57.**